# Why Auto Update does not work for sample MyApp using Squirrel.Windows

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, squirrel.windows

As per [documentation](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/develop/docs/getting-started/5-updating.md) I followed all the steps but the application did not update to 3.0.0. Which I suppose should happen automatically when App was opened. (It stayed at 1.0.0)
[image]

---

[image]

1. I updated the Assembly Info version:
   [image]
2. Did release again from Visual Studio
3. Updated Nuget meta data in Nuger package manager
   [image]
4. Executed squirrel --releasify MyApp.3.0.0.nupkg
   [image]

This indeed created new .nupkg with 3.0.0:
[image]

P.S. I'm trying 1.0.0 to 3.0.0 as an example.

App was indeed 3.0.0 when running directly from Visual Studio
[image]

My releases folder has been set correctly:
**Folder Path:**
[image]
**In Code**
[image]

In `%LocalApp\MyApp` version 3.0.0 had not been downloaded:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learnt that Main method must be async and await must be used.

[image]